# Why OOM? And first gc why Tenured: 8192K->8961K(10240K)?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

My code:

```
public class TestJVmRiZHI{   
/**
 jdk 1.8
 -XX:+UseSerialGC
 -verbose:gc
 -Xms20M
 -Xmx20m
 -Xmn10M
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails
 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
 * @param args
 */     

  private  static final int _1mb = 1024 * 1024;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte[] allocation1 = new Byte[2*_1mb];
    Byte[] allocation2 = new Byte[2*_1mb];
    Byte[] allocation3 = new Byte[2*_1mb];
    Byte[] allocation4 = new Byte[4*_1mb];
  }
}
```

Result:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at controller.TestJVmRiZHI.main(TestJVmRiZHI.java:24)
>
> [GC (Allocation Failure) [DefNew: 2540K->770K(9216K), 0.0034872 secs]
>
> [Tenured: 8192K->8961K(10240K), 0.0071963 secs] 10732K->8961K(19456K),
>
> [Metaspace: 3385K->3385K(1056768K)], 0.0107478 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [Tenured: 8961K->8943K(10240K), 0.0073261 secs] 8961K->8943K(19456K), [Metaspace: 3385K->3385K(1056768K)], 0.0073536 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
>
> Heap
>    def new generation   total 9216K, used 410K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)
>
> eden space 8192K,   5% used [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000fec66800, 0x00000000ff400000)
>
> from space 1024K,   0% used [0x00000000ff500000, 0x00000000ff500000, 0x00000000ff600000)
>
> to   space 1024K,   0% used [0x00000000ff400000, 0x00000000ff400000, 0x00000000ff500000)
>
> tenured generation   total 10240K, used 8943K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
>
> the space 10240K,  87% used [0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ffebbd38, 0x00000000ffebbe00, 0x0000000100000000)
>
> Metaspace       used 3429K, capacity 4494K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
>
> class space    used 382K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576

Comment: Um well you are allocating 10.5 million `Byte` objects, you need 160+ MB for that...

Comment: @xTrollxDudex `new Byte[2*_1mb]` only allocates one object: The array of 2097152 references, all `null`. Assuming a reference is 4 bytes (32-bit or CompressedOops), that means 8 MB (+ object header).

Comment: Ah, null references... My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Byte[]` is an array of Object References.

An object reference is usually 4 bytes. On a 64-bit machine with more then 32 GB of heap, an object reference is 8 bytes.

So, assuming 4 bytes, 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 4 = **8 MB**.

So:

```
allocation1:  8 MB
allocation2:  8 MB
allocation3:  8 MB
allocation4: 16 MB
             =====
      total: 40 MB
```

With only `-Xmx20m` you run out of memory.

You probably meant for `new Byte[2*_1mb]` to allocate 2 MB, so **change `Byte` to `byte`**, so the array is an array of Primitive `byte` values, not an array of Object References.

Comment: tks,thank you for An object reference is usually 4 bytes.

Comment: sorry,i hava a  another question. i change Byte to byte.    first gc : DefNew: 6636K->781K(9216K) and  finally eden space 8192K,  77% used,tenured generation   total 10240K, used 4096K.     i think byte[4*1Mb] should allocate  def new generation and three byte[2*1Mb] after gc should allocate tenured generation.